# CSS - Align div to bottom respective his parent div

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align div # alignBottom1 and # alignBottom2 down without removing the float left from the parent div and without using position absolute or margin top.

How can I do?

This is my code:

```css
#TotContainer {
  height: 900px;
}

#container {
  max-height: 90%
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="TotContainer">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:blue;">XXXXXX</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:red;">
      <div id="alignBottom1">Text to align at the bottom 1</div>
      <div id="alignBottom2">Text to align at the bottom 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can add a sketch of the desired result...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily if you turn the parent container into a flexbox.

In your sample, I gave the parent a height value so that you can see the effect of using flexbox and justifying the content to the end of it's parent.

```css
#alignBottom {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 100px; /* giving the element a height to exaggerate the effect */
}

#TotContainer {
  height: 900px;
}

#container {
  max-height: 90%
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="TotContainer">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:blue;">XXXXXX</div>
    <div id="alignBottom" class="col-sm-6" style="background:red;">
      <div id="alignBottom1">Text to align at the bottom 1</div>
      <div id="alignBottom2">Text to align at the bottom 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Last question please: If i have two div inside #alignBottom2 and i want that the first is align top and the second align to bottome how can i do?

Comment: You can do that by changing the `justify-content` property to `justify-content: space-between;`

Answer (score 1):

CSS flexbox helps aligning the content inside the container in multiple ways with few lines of code. This might work for you.

```css
#TotContainer {
  height: 900px;
}

#container {
  max-height: 90%
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.col-sm-6:nth-child(2){
 /* adding this */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /* adding some height to the container for better visibility od effect */
  height: 80px;
}

.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="TotContainer">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:blue;">XXXXXX</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background:red;">
      <div id="alignBottom1">Text to align at the bottom 1</div>
      <div id="alignBottom2">Text to align at the bottom 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```